# get method doesnt work on php rest web service

Tags: php, mysql, rest

Excuse me,i try to make restful web service with request method POST and GET, i finally success with GETmethod to view data on mysql, but when i use POST method to search data or delete data anything with POST method doesnt work. i dont know why... chek this out

```
private function users(){
    // Cross validation if the request method is GET else it will return "Not Acceptable" status
    if($this->get_request_method() != "GET") {
        $this->response('',406);
    }
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, user_fullname, user_email FROM users WHERE user_status = 1", $this->db);
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
        $result = array();
        while($rlt = mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            $result[] = $rlt;
        }
        // If success everythig is good send header as "OK" and return list of users in JSON format
        $this->response($this->json($result), 200);
    }
    $this->response('',204);    // If no records "No Content" status
}
```

then DELETE method

```
private function deleteUser() {
    // Cross validation if the request method is DELETE else it will return "Not Acceptable" status
    if($this->get_request_method() != "DELETE"){
        $this->response('',406);
    }
    $id = (int)$this->_request['id'];
    if($id > 0) {
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = $id");
        $success = array('status' => "Success", "msg" => "Successfully one record deleted.");
        $this->response($this->json($success),200);
    } else
        $this->response('',204);    // If no records "No Content" status
}
```

Comment: How are you making your POST requests?

Comment: Also, don't use the `mysql` extensions, use the `mysqli` or `PDO` and  extensions *prepared statements* instead.

Comment: i make some POST request to delete data, i use rest client chrome plugin to test my web service.., i use mysql for database, what is PDO extention?? sorry im really new one.

Comment: In the same way that mysql and mysqli are extensions that allow you to access MySQL databases, PDO is an extension that allows you to access any database that has a corresponding dialect extension. http://au2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php.  Uncomment `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` (or *.so) in your php.ini to enable, and use the classes from the link to access the database, via preparedStatements or queries.

Answer (score 1):

Your users() and deleteUser() functions specifically check for a REQUEST_METHOD of GET and DELETE respectively.  Therefore, if either of those functions are called when a POST is done, they will both return `406`.

**Update:** In answer of the comment: What should I do to fix that?

If the same functions are expected to work with POST, as well as their respective primary REQUEST_METHOD, then you need to allow the POST request method to be validated.

```
private function users(){
    // Cross validation if the request method is GET else it will return "Not Acceptable" status
    if ($this->get_request_method() != 'GET' && $this->get_request_method() != 'POST')  {
        $this->response('',406);
    }
```

and

```
private function deleteUser() {
    // Cross validation if the request method is DELETE else it will return "Not Acceptable" status
    if ($this->get_request_method() != 'DELETE' && $this->get_request_method() != 'POST') {
        $this->response('',406);
    }
```

For the `deleteUser` function, I'm assuming that `$this->_request` is sourced from $_REQUEST, and can pick up `id` from the query string or from the form post.

Since you've only shown these two functions, I can't be sure that there isn't other code that will redirect the action somewhere else, if the request is a POST.

Comment: sorry so what should i do to fix that?

Comment: Updated to show modifications required to let POST processing occur.

Comment: oke thanks for all feedback i finally succes delete method, i change the $id like this : $id = ISSET($_GET['user']) then i've change the Request method to GET not DELETE anymore, :)

Comment: then what the function of DELETE HTTP request method web service ??? if we can use GET HTTP request to DELETE the data with WEB Service, should we use DELETE request_method to delete with web service?? im not sure

Comment: Don't use GET to delete data for a web service.  Only use DELETE or POST (with specific action) to delete data for a web service. And use GET to get data for a web service.

Comment: oke thanks reuben i used POST to Delete data with web service and i've tested to Restful client chrome, its workm but use DELETE to delete data with web service doesnt work :) then,without restful client chrome can i test with browser??? i try to test like this localhost/rest/test.php?action=delete&user=me but no data output or anything else

Comment: Can you link to the Chrome extension you are using to test?